# How do i aggregate data from 2 columns referencing another table and also get the monthly totals for the past 3 months?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Using the data below:

1. How do I get the sum of the cost of each incident based on two columns (crime_incidentid, similar_incidentid) in the `listofincidents` table?
2. Also how do I get the sums for the past 3 months (January, February and March)?

   ```
   create table crimeincidents (
     id int not null,
     name varchar(20),
     primary key (id)
   );

   create table listofincidents (
     id int not null,
     incidentdate datetime not null,
     crime_incidentid int not null,
     similar_incidentid int not null,
     cost_to_city decimal(8,2),
     primary key (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (crime_incidentid) REFERENCES crimeincidents(id),
     FOREIGN KEY (similar_incidentid) REFERENCES crimeincidents(id)
   ); 

   insert into crimeincidents  (id,name) values 
     (1,'Burglary'),
     (2,'Theft'),
     (3,'Grand theft auto');

   insert into listofincidents (id, incidentdate, crime_incidentid,
     similar_incidentid, cost_to_city) 
    values
     (1, "2018-01-10 18:48:00", 1, 2, 900),
     (2, "2018-02-15 14:48:00", 2, 3, 800),
     (3, "2018-02-20 18:10:00", 3, 1, 1500.10), 
     (4, "2018-03-20 18:48:00", 1, 3, 800.23),
     (5, "2018-03-25 18:24:00", 1, 3, 200.00),
     (6, "2018-04-15 10:12:00", 1, 2, 400.00);
   ```

The query to generate the results without monthly dates is:

```
select c.id, c.name, sm.similarIncidentCost, cr.crimeIncidentCost 
  from crimeincidents c
  inner join (
    select c.id, sum(s.cost_to_city) similarIncidentCost 
    from crimeincidents c inner join listofincidents s 
                          on s.similar_incidentid = c.id
    group by c.id
  ) sm on sm.id = c.id
  inner join (
     select c.id, sum(cr.cost_to_city) crimeIncidentCost 
       from crimeincidents c inner join listofincidents cr 
                             on cr.crime_incidentid = c.id
       group by c.id
  ) cr on cr.id = c.id;
```

I want to generate the costs using the past 3 months data. The final result should look like this:

```
1. January   | 1500.1   |   1900.23
2. February  | 900      |   800
3. March     | 1800.23  |   1500.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(li.incidentdate, '%Y-%m') as date,
ci.name,
SUM(
li.cost_to_city
) as totalCost
FROM crimeincidents ci
JOIN listofincidents li ON ci.id = li.crime_incidentid OR ci.id = li.similar_incidentid
GROUP BY date, ci.id
ORDER BY date
```

And you can go with :

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(li.incidentdate), ' ', MONTHNAME(li.incidentdate)) as month,
ci.name,
SUM(
li.cost_to_city
) as totalCost
FROM crimeincidents ci
JOIN listofincidents li ON ci.id = li.crime_incidentid OR ci.id = li.similar_incidentid
GROUP BY month, ci.id
ORDER BY month
```

To match your request better.

Didn't notice at first you wanted "incident" and "similar incident" sums separated. Although I find it weird (since a similar incident can himself have a similar incident) I did the query :

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(li.incidentdate), ' ', MONTHNAME(li.incidentdate)) as month,
ci.name,
SUM(
IF(ci.id = li.id, li.cost_to_city,0)
) as totalCostIncident,
SUM(
IF(ci.id = li.similar_incidentid, li.cost_to_city,0)
) as totalCostSimilarIncident
FROM crimeincidents ci
JOIN listofincidents li ON ci.id = li.crime_incidentid OR ci.id = li.similar_incidentid
GROUP BY month, ci.id
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: This works but it is not the perfect answer. I wanted it to be summed up for each month versus each month being listed. see my fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8eaee/4/0

Comment: I don't get it, if you sum per month only, what's the point of displaying the incident name in the result, since it will include different incident's costs ?

Comment: How do i get the total per month. instead of display multiple January . It should be a single January with the corresponding total.

Comment: Refer to my previous comment. You can remove the ci.id from the GROUP BY statement, but there is no point in keeping the ci.name in the SELECT since each month can include multiple incident